# What does pythonapi.PyObject_GC_UnTrack return?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, garbage-collection, ctypes

Say I define a container object (list, in our case), automatically tracked by the CPython's GC. Then decide to untrack it using ctypes's pythonapi function. The documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/gcsupport.html#c.PyObject_GC_UnTrack) that PyObject_GC_UnTrack returns void, yet, when calling it via pythonapi, it returns an integer which is not the memory address of the object being untracked nor its pointer.

```
>>>import ctypes
>>>from ctypes import pythonapi, py_object
>>>import gc
>>>a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>>pythonapi.PyObject_GC_UnTrack(py_object(a))
-396907592
>>>gc.is_tracked(a)
False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `ctypes` docs:

> ctypes.pythonapi
>
> An instance of PyDLL that exposes Python C API functions as attributes. Note that
>   all these functions are assumed to return C int, which is of course not always
>   the truth, so you have to assign the correct restype attribute to use these
>   functions.

And it's generally true (not just specific to `pythonapi`) that `ctypes` assumes functions return C ints.

```
>>> pythonapi.PyObject_GC_UnTrack.restype
<class 'ctypes.c_long'>
```

(On this box, `int` is the same as `long`).

If that matters, you have to set `restype` yourself:

```
>>> pythonapi.PyObject_GC_UnTrack.restype = None # which means "void"
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> pythonapi.PyObject_GC_UnTrack(py_object(a))
[no output]
```

It's true that `PyObject_GC_UnTrack` returns `void`; so long as `ctypes` believes it returns an int, `ctypes` returns garbage bytes.  Here from `Modules/gcmodule.c`:

```
void
PyObject_GC_UnTrack(void *op)
{
    /* Obscure:  the Py_TRASHCAN mechanism requires that we be able to
     * call PyObject_GC_UnTrack twice on an object.
     */
    if (IS_TRACKED(op))
        _PyObject_GC_UNTRACK(op);
}
```